# Ajax with Zendframework

Tags: ajax, zend-framework

Friends,

How I integrate Ajax with zendframework.I need some good tutorials.

Answer (score 3):

Put this in your controller

```
public function init()
{
    $contextSwitch = $this->_helper->getHelper('contextSwitch');
    $contextSwitch->addActionContext('test', 'json')
                  ->initContext();
}
```

create a test action

```
public function testAction()
{
    $this->view->var1 = "I'm testing";
}
```

Then use jquery to perform the request in your view

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#display').ajaxStart(function(){
        $(this).html('Loading...');   
    });

    str = $('#test').val();
    $('#link').bind('click',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.post(
        this.href,
        { var1: str, format: 'json' }, 
        function(data){
            $('#display').html(data.var1);
        },
        "json"
        );          

    });

});

</script>
<input type="text" name="test" id="test" value="just testing" />
<p>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'test')); ?>" id="link">Testar</a>
</p>

<div id="display">...</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this in your controller:

```
    public function testAction() {
        // Remove all of your HTML stuff
        $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
        // PHP to create an array form database or something
        // This will return the info as json. It takes care of the header and everything else!
        return $this->_helper->json->sendJson( array('test') );
    }
```